# What is the better way to flatten a jsonb object in postgresql query

Tags: json, postgresql

i have a simulated table with 2 columns including a nested jsonb column

```
CREATE TABLE public.test
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('test_id_seq'::regclass),
  testcol jsonb
)

INSERT INTO public.test (testcol) VALUES 
('[{"type": {"value": 1, "displayName": "flag1"}, "value": "10"}, {"type": {"value": 2, "displayName": "flag2"}, "value": "20"}, {"type": {"value": 3, "displayName": "flag3"}, "value": "30"}, {"type": {"value": 4, "displayName": "flag4"}}, {"type": {"value": 5, "displayName": "flag5"}}, {"type": {"value": 6, "displayName": "flag6"}, "value": "40"}]')
,('[{"type": {"value": "x", "displayName": "flag1"}, "value": "x10"}, {"type": {"value": "y", "displayName": "flag2"}, "value": "x20"}, {"type": {"value": "z", "displayName": "flag3"}, "value": "x30"}]')
;
```

so i trying to return a table of values where it has the main table values, and values from within the jsonb object. I can achieve it with the following query

```
SELECT  id ,jo1.obj->'value', jo2.obj->'value', jo3.obj->'value'
FROM    test
CROSS JOIN
        LATERAL
        (
        SELECT  JSON_OBJECT_AGG(jt.key, jt.value) obj
        FROM    JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(testcol) je
        CROSS JOIN
                LATERAL JSONB_EACH(je.value) jt
        WHERE je@>'{ "type": { "displayName": "flag1"} }'
        ) jo1
CROSS JOIN
        LATERAL
        (
        SELECT  JSON_OBJECT_AGG(jt.key, jt.value) obj
        FROM    JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(testcol) je
        CROSS JOIN
                LATERAL JSONB_EACH(je.value) jt
        WHERE je@>'{ "type": { "displayName": "flag2"} }'
        ) jo2
CROSS JOIN
        LATERAL
        (
        SELECT  JSON_OBJECT_AGG(jt.key, jt.value) obj
        FROM    JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(testcol) je
        CROSS JOIN
                LATERAL JSONB_EACH(je.value) jt
        WHERE je@>'{ "type": { "displayName": "flag3"} }'
        ) jo3
```

I'll be working with lots of data, so i wondering is there a better way to achieve the same result, as this look like loads of inner queries and i am not too sure performance impact doing it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variant of a pivot problem for which you can use conditional aggregation:

```
select t.id,
       max(j.data ->> 'value') filter (where j.data -> 'type' ->> 'displayName' = 'flag1') as flag1,
       max(j.data ->> 'value') filter (where j.data -> 'type' ->> 'displayName' = 'flag2') as flag2,
       max(j.data ->> 'value') filter (where j.data -> 'type' ->> 'displayName' = 'flag3') as flag3
from test t
  cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(t.testcol) as j(data)
group by t.id
order by t.id;
```

---

If you are already using Postgres 12, this is even easier using the new JSON Path functions:

```
select id,
       jsonb_path_query(testcol, '$[*] ? (@.type.displayName == "flag1").value') as flag1,
       jsonb_path_query(testcol, '$[*] ? (@.type.displayName == "flag2").value') as flag2,
       jsonb_path_query(testcol, '$[*] ? (@.type.displayName == "flag2").value') as flag3
from test;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=7951a9a5c3bcf0da5ce96b77e459cb7c)